# Modifying xml definition of a running KVM domain via script

Tags: scripting, vi, virsh

How can I modify the xml definition of a VM over ssh?
I know that I can do this interactively by logging into the host and using:

```
virsh edit <domain name>
```

But I want to automate this modification of xml using a script that runs on a remote host and then executes commands over ssh on the KVM box.

From what I have observed is that virsh edit is opening the default editor (vi in my case) for me to edit the file. I want to somehow overwrite this file (which is interactively opened by virsh edit command) with vm definition contained in another text file.

I have found threads on how text can be piped to vi using:

```
cat <file name> | vi -
```

But that wont work in my case since,

1. virsh is opening up default editor with arguments that I have no control over. (or at least I don't know how to modify those arguments)
2. The default editor could be different on different KVM boxes.

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Edit: Just wanted to make clear that I do not have an option to power off the VM and redefine it. I want to modify a *running* domain.

Comment: Even i'm working on similar thing. Did it work with virsh dumpxml & virsh define? Please let me know

Answer (score 5):

Use `virsh dumpxml` to get the XML, and then `virsh define` to replace the domain definition with your modifications.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I tried that but when I dump the xml definition again, I don't see the changes that I made before redefining the VM.

Comment: You didn't tell us you tried that! Tell us everything you did.

Comment: And remember that some changes take effect the next time you shut down the guest.

Comment: Oh, I just tried that after receiving your suggestion.